# Why does this code show me a lot of space?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, c

I want to make a 4hz reading of GSR and temperature, in the following format for every second:

```
697,20.8744
696,20.86521
695,20.8653
699,20.8777
```

The print, in python, would be print(GSR+","+Temp)
The tries in C are giving problem, here's my actual code:

```
#include <OneWire.h>

const int GSR=A0;
int threshold=0;
int sensorValue;
unsigned long startTime = 0;
#define MEASURE_PERIOD 250
OneWire  ds(3);

void setup(){
  long sum=0;
  Serial.begin(115200);

  for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
  {
  sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
  sum += sensorValue;
  delay(5);
  }
  threshold = sum/500;
  }

void loop()
{
  byte i;
  byte present = 0;
  byte type_s;
  byte data[12];
  byte addr[8];
  float celsius;
    if((millis() - startTime) >= MEASURE_PERIOD)
    {
        startTime += MEASURE_PERIOD;
        // Do your job, such as
        sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
        Serial.print(sensorValue);
        Serial.print(",");
        if ( !ds.search(addr)) {
    ds.reset_search();
    return;
  }



  if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
      return;
  }
  // the first ROM byte indicates which chip


  ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);
  ds.write(0x44, 1);        // start conversion, with parasite power on at the end

   // maybe 750ms is enough, maybe not
  // we might do a ds.depower() here, but the reset will take care of it.

  present = ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);    
  ds.write(0xBE);         // Read Scratchpad

  for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) {           // we need 9 bytes
    data[i] = ds.read();
  }

  // Convert the data to actual temperature
  // because the result is a 16 bit signed integer, it should
  // be stored to an "int16_t" type, which is always 16 bits
  // even when compiled on a 32 bit processor.
  int16_t raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
  if (type_s) {
    raw = raw << 3; // 9 bit resolution default
    if (data[7] == 0x10) {
      // "count remain" gives full 12 bit resolution
      raw = (raw & 0xFFF0) + 12 - data[6];
    }
  } else {
    byte cfg = (data[4] & 0x60);
    // at lower res, the low bits are undefined, so let's zero them
    if (cfg == 0x00) raw = raw & ~7;  // 9 bit resolution, 93.75 ms
    else if (cfg == 0x20) raw = raw & ~3; // 10 bit res, 187.5 ms
    else if (cfg == 0x40) raw = raw & ~1; // 11 bit res, 375 ms
    //// default is 12 bit resolution, 750 ms conversion time
  }
  celsius = (float)raw / 16.0;
  Serial.print(celsius);

    }
    Serial.println("\n");

}
```

How can I reach the upper format?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of what you print, your loop boils down to:

```
if (millis() - startTime >= MEASURE_PERIOD) {
    startTime += MEASURE_PERIOD;
    sensorValue = ...;
    celcius = ...;
    Serial.print(sensorValue);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(celsius);
}
Serial.println("\n");
```

You are printing *two* newlines on every loop iteration. One is written
as `"\n"`, the other is the “ln” of `Serial.println` (“println” means
“print some stuff followed by a new line character sequence”). Instead,
you probably want to print a *single* newline, and only when there is
actual data being printed:

```
if (millis() - startTime >= MEASURE_PERIOD) {
    startTime += MEASURE_PERIOD;
    sensorValue = ...;
    celcius = ...;
    Serial.print(sensorValue);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(celsius);  // notice the ln in println
}
```

But since you are doing nothing else in `loop()`, you could simplify a
bit and avoid having everything inside a big `if` statement:

```
if (millis() - startTime < MEASURE_PERIOD)
    return;

startTime += MEASURE_PERIOD;
sensorValue = ...;
celcius = ...;
Serial.print(sensorValue);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(celsius);
```

**Edit**: Here is a simple test demonstrating this logic. In both the
second and the third case, it generates an output in the requested
format.

```
const uint32_t MEASURE_PERIOD = 250;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    static uint32_t startTime;
#ifdef SECOND_CASE
    if (millis() - startTime >= MEASURE_PERIOD) {
        startTime += MEASURE_PERIOD;
        int sensorValue = random(695, 699);
        float celsius = map(sensorValue, 695, 699, 208653, 208777) / 1e4;
        Serial.print(sensorValue);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.println(celsius, 3);  // notice the ln in println
    }
#else  // third case
    if (millis() - startTime < MEASURE_PERIOD)
        return;

    startTime += MEASURE_PERIOD;
    int sensorValue = random(695, 699);
    float celsius = map(sensorValue, 695, 699, 208653, 208777) / 1e4;
    Serial.print(sensorValue);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(celsius, 3);  // notice the ln in println
#endif
}
```

Comment: Why do you say putting the print outside the if will simplify things?

Comment: Maybe “simplify” is not the right word, but it will remove one nesting level to most of your code. I (among others) find this is better for readability.

Comment: In the second case I have lines like that:
691,690,20.81


The third case doesn't work

Comment: @GabrieleGiordano: Then you have either a communication error, or an error somewhere else in your code. C.f. the test I added as an edit.

Comment: I think it's much slower than 250ms. If i put 1000 at the beginning, it gives me a print ever 2 seconds I think

Comment: In the third code you wrote, the startTime += MEASURE_PERIOD; is just outside the big if?

Comment: I confirm the suspect: it's one reading every sec, I compared with data of another sensor that works at 1hz. I had the same number of elements in the array

Comment: Precisely it's 2hz instead of 4

Comment: @GabrieleGiordano: Your sensor may be slow to respond, or you may have some other problem elsewhere in your program: different problem → different question. The test code above, on my Arduino Uno, outputs 4 lines per second.

Comment: the problems seem to be the sensor, that can't read at 4hz

Comment: but with another code seems to work. Anyway, its' a matter of another question